# Group Click event in Expandable List

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

Is it possible to customise group click event in MvxExpandableListView ?. I have tried to use GroupClick by providing command but no luck. I want to use GroupClick event if there is no child is available.

Comment: yes you can. In GroupClick first you need to check child count

Comment: Can you please add more information about the same ? I am looking for information about mvvmcross xamarin framework

Comment: Why downvote for the question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, i am able to make it work.

Instead of setting GroupClick property in code, bind this property in xml and provide the corresponding command to bind it.

```
 <Mvx.MvxExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/toclist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource SegmentTasks; ItemClick SelectTicketItemCommand; GroupClick SelectTicketParentCommand"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/ticketlistchildview"
        local:GroupItemTemplate="@layout/listticketitem"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:groupIndicator="@null" 
        android:childDivider="#00000000"/>
```

Comment: Hello can you please share the code for working with MvxExpandableListView